# issue with JSZip 3.0

Tags: jquery, jszip

I have an error with JSZip 3.0. I am making a code for creating and download zip for that I am using the JSZip library.

and my code to create a zip is given below.

```js
var zip = new JSZip();
var urls = ["image/Screenshot (11).png","image/Screenshot (10).png"];
var count = 0;
var zipFilename = "zipFilename.zip";
urls.forEach(function(url){
  var filename = "filename";
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
     if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle the error
     }
     zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
     count++;
     if (count == urls.length) {
       var zipFile = zip.generate({type: "blob"});
       saveAs(zipFile, zipFilename);
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.1/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.1.0/jszip-utils.js"></script>
```

with that I have received error `Uncaught Error: Error: This method has been removed in JSZip 3.0, please check the upgrade guide. at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange`

when I research this error I have found one answer [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242927/how-fix-error-this-method-has-been-removed-in-jszip-3-0-please-check-the-upgra) but I don't understand how and where can I use this.

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.1/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.1.0/jszip-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var zip = new JSZip();
var urls = ["logo.png","foot-logo.png"];
var count = 0;
var zipFilename = "zipFilename.zip";
urls.forEach(function(url){
  var filename = "filename";
  console.log(url);
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {

     if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle the error
     }
     zip.file(url, data, {binary:true});
     count++;
     if (count == urls.length) {
       zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function (blob) {
    saveAs(blob, zipFilename);
});
     }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
Javascript zip file
</body>
</html>
```